# How to stop foreach cycle without stopping the rest of the PHP script?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Having a `foreach` loop, is it possible to stop it if a certain condition becomes valid?

#### Example:

```
<?php
foreach ($foo as $bar) {

  if (2+2 === 4) {
    // Do something and stop the cycle
  }

}
?>
```

*I tried to use `return` and `exit`, but it didn't work as expected, because I want to continue executing the remaining of the PHP script.*

Comment: have you tries using `continue` and/or `break` ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php):

```
foreach($foo as $bar) {    
    if(2 + 2 === 4) {
        break;    
    }    
}
```

Break will jump out of the `foreach` loop and continue execution normally. If you want to skip just one iteration, you can use [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

Comment: what if I have a foreach into another foreach and only need to break the inner foreach?????

Comment: That's what happens, `break` stops only the innermost loop. To break out of more than the innermost loop, use `break 2;`, where the number is the amount of nested loops you want to break out of.

Answer (score 5):

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php is the answer!

As simple as `break;`.